# Como puedo aplicar la PROGRAMACIÓN ORIENTA A OBJETOS en c#

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes amigos, mi inquietud consiste en que tengo un algoritmo que evita que dentro de un vector se repitan los numeros del 0 al 9 asignados por un random, ahora lo que quiero aprender es como usar ese algorimo para llegan una matriz con el mismo random pero que igual forma no se repitan, llamando al algoritmo que ya valida eso.
Gracias por su ayuda.
c#

```
int[] vector = new int[10];
        Console.WriteLine("El vector del 0 al 9 sin repetir es:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < vector.Length; i++)
    {
        Boolean validacion = true;
        while (validacion)
        {
            int valor = aleatorio.Next(0, 10);
            for (int j = 0; j < vector.Length; j++)
            {
                if (valor == vector[j])
                {
                    validacion = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    validacion = false;
                }
            }
            vector[i] = valor;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(vector[i].ToString());
    }
```

Para usarlo dentro de este y no se repitan los numero en la matriz:

```
int posi = 0, posj = 0, mayor = 0;//declaracion de variables para la posicion y el numero mayor

    Console.WriteLine("Matriz de 10*10\n");

    int[,] matriz = new int[11, 11];  //Creacion de la matriz de 10*10 (10filas, 10 columnas)
    Random aleatorio = new Random();//declaracion del random para llenar la matriz 

    //se recorre la matriz para asignar los valores
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            matriz[i, j] = aleatorio.Next(0, 100);
        }
```

Mi inquietud consiste en que tengo un algoritmo que evita que dentro de un vector se repitan los numeros del 0 al 9 asignados por un random, ahora lo que quiero aprender es como usar ese algorimo para llegan una matriz con el mismo random pero que igual forma no se repitan, llamando al algoritmo que ya valida eso.

c#

```
    // se recorre nuevamente para leer sus valores y validar cual es mayor y capturar su respectiva posicion
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (matriz[i, j] > mayor)//si matriz en la posicion i,j es > mayor
                {
                    mayor = matriz[i, j]; // a mayor -> el valor que hay en la posicion i, j
                    posi = i; // a la posicion i -> i
                    posj = j;// a la posicion j -> j
```

Comment: Hola.. deberías ser mucho mas claro con lo que necesitas. Como es el algoritmo, el código del mismo, como quieres llamarlo. La respuesta a tu pregunta en este momento es, llamándolo cada vez que agregas un numero. y eso no ayuda en nada.

Comment: este es el alrgoritmo que en valida que no se repitan los numeros,

Comment: necesitamos ver el codigo que tenes para poder ayudarte.. fijate en [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Mas allá de que en tu código no veo ninguna función para validar (hay una función que llena un vector y va validando en ese momento si se repite o no, lo hace mal...), no entiendo que tiene que ver esto con programación orientada a objetos.

Sacando de lado todas esas objeciones, la siguiente seccion de codigo valida un vector para que no tenga repetidos:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < vector.Length; j++)
 {
     if (valor == vector[j])
     {
         validacion = true;
         break;
     }
     else
     {
         validacion = false;
     }
 }
```

y tenes una función que llena una matriz...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
         matriz[i, j] = aleatorio.Next(0, 100);
    }
```

entonces.. si mezclamos los dos partes de código.. nos damos cuenta para recorrer la matriz hacen falta 2 for.. uno para columnas y otro para filas.. y que por cada numero que querramos ingresar, tenemos que chequear contra todo el resto que no exista ya (algo raro en matrices, pero lo dejamos para otro momento)...